# Android studio (Gradle) doesn't create signed apk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

In order to Mock server response for Espresso I decided to create a new Build Type. I tried to do it via Project settings and I got some errors, so I decided to add it manually.

I have following configuration in `build.gradle` file - in root of my project:

```
androidConfiguration = {
        signingConfigs {
            debug {
                storeFile file("$rootProject.projectDir/debug.keystore")
                storePassword "android"
                keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
                keyPassword "android"
            }

            release {
                storeFile file("$rootProject.projectDir/androd-prod.keystore")
                storePassword System.getenv("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
                keyAlias System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")
                keyPassword System.getenv("KEY_PASSWORD")
            }
        }
}
```

I added new `mock` build type  in `build.gradle` file of my main module.

```
    buildTypes {
        mock {
            // Setup default urls
            buildConfigField "String", "MY_URL_BASE", "\"\""

            // Enabling multidex support.
            multiDexEnabled true

            dexOptions {
                incremental true
                javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            }

            applicationIdSuffix '.mock'
            versionNameSuffix '-mock'
            debuggable true
        }

        debug {...}

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ...
        }

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { v ->
                def f = v.outputFile
                def sha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute().text.trim()
                def fname = f.name.replace(".apk", "-${defaultConfig.versionName}-${defaultConfig.versionCode}-${sha}.apk")
                v.outputFile = new File(f.parent, fname)
            }
        }
    }
```

I run `./gradlew clean aGM` command and application compile successfully. However, there is `x` sign on my build configuration. So, any idea where is my mistake?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your mock buildType to use the default debug signingConfig:

```
buildTypes {
    mock {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

This will also enable the gradle task `installMock`, which would be unavailable without a signingConfig.  `assembleMock` just creates an unsigned build without it.

Comment: omg!! I actually did it after I typed `.` it just suggested me the `release`. Since I don't have it in my `debug` type I decided to not use it. Based on your suggested I copy/pasted and it worked. Thanks Doug ;)

Comment: I was searching for this for 2 years... My man! you saved me :)